# 2011 Jeep Compass Cooling fans don't run

Tags: jeep, relay, cooling, compass

2011 Jeep Compass with the 2.4

So far replaced thermostats and temp sensor. both fans do not run , even with Ac on and temp setting an alert.

fuses check good, fan relays and the box are clean and filled with dielectric grease and no corrosion found.
Direct power to each fan via the relay terminals makes them run.
AC fan only runs on high Rad fan runs on both speeds
relays read as having power at their inputs.

My wiring does not match the wiring diagrams from alldata. where can I find a different wiring diagram that shows the correct wiring colors?
Ac Fan wires are Green with red and Black with white that go to 2 different relays,
Rad fan( right when facing vehicle )  has 2 purple or violet wires that go to 2 different relays

now down to assuming the trigger signals from tipm are questionable or a sensor is not sending the right info. still probing and checking to see if any relay signals change, but am now lost in the wiring

system stays cool while moving, but overheats quickly when stopped at idle

Dad in Garage going nuts APPRECIATE ANY INPUT

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked the relays directly? A relay can "look good" but not function.

Comment: I have swapped all 5 relays by by 1 position, still have the same results will pull them all and test them manually just to confirm function thanks.

Comment: You might also put a jumper in place of a relay to see if the fans kick on manually. If the relay checks out through testing and the fans kick on when manually jumped, it would verify the wiring, power, fans, and relay. This would point directly back at the signal not being given to turn them on.

Comment: manually tested all 5 relays. all seemed to function, so I went further. two of the five have much higher resistance when closed than the other 3, all 5 are marked identically off to replace those two as a next step. failed signaling is where I am looking to next. will try probing the trigger inputs of the relays under demand. Thanks

Comment: Are fans three wire types? Three wire fans suggests two speeds and a fan control module to operate both fans at up to  three speeds using complex wiring in the fcm. Low speed may have burned out leaving only high speed when the engine overheats. A hint of possible fan problems; ac usually demands cooling fan operation because the ac condenser coil (sitting in front of the radiator) heats up from compressing refrigerant. If the fan(s) aren't running then the cooling system will overheat as hot air from the condenser coil flows into the hot radiator.

Comment: replaced two questionable relays, reassembled and now have AC fan running, still no rad fans yet, but does not seem to be overheating with ac on, will now test with ac off.

Comment: fans are 2 wire, and they run when powered from relay contact points. seems the pcm signals the TIPM to operate the rad fan speeds, so now testing it to see if it still overheats.

Answer (score 0):

You said that the ralays are good but the fans will not run automaticly, If this gets too desperate then buy a temp switch and wire this to your fans .The fans do draw lots of current .My aftermarket fan takes 18Amps running at 12VDC .If the temp switch that you buy doesnot have a proper current rating then run the temp switch into your relay coils .Sure every vechile is a little different but erring on the side of caution I went for 70 degrees celcius